# MVC - Loading screen / disable button before and after downloading a file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, download

So i have a button to download a csv file. The button simple does:

```
$("#btnExportToContactList").click(function (e) {
    window.location.href = '/Home/ExportList';
});
```

My action simply returns a

```
File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv), "text/csv", filename);
```

Everything is working fine. Now since I'm building a csv when pressing the button and since the process can take some time, I want to put up a loading screen or simply disable the button while they wait. My problem is how to disable/enable the button?

I have tried the following but it doesn't work because the browser is being redirected to another page and it will stop executing my Javascript.

```
$("#btnExportToContactList").click(function (e) {
    $("#btnExportToContactList").attr("disabled", true);
    window.location.href = '/Home/ExportList';
    $("#btnExportToContactList").attr("disabled", false);
});
```

but its not working. Anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: What i need is a way to disable after the file is downloaded

Comment: So, do you want to restrict the download only once per user or something along the same lines?

Comment: Since this is a process that can take some time, I want to disable the button (and thus not allowing more clicks on it) while I'm preparing the file to be downloaded. As soon as the file is ready, I want to re-enable the button

Comment: But you'd be redirected as soon as you click the button! Where/when does the prepare happen?

Comment: window.location.href = '/Home/ExportList'; where '/Home/ExportList' is an action on my controller. This is server side

Answer (score 0):

You can set `disabled` property to `false` each time page is ready or loaded.

```
$(function(){
   $("#btnExportToContactList").attr("disabled", false);

  $("#btnExportToContactList").click(function (e) {
    $("#btnExportToContactList").attr("disabled", true);
    window.location.href = '/Home/ExportList';
  });
});
```

Update: If above isnt working, you can try workaround like this. Rather than calling `window.location.href` you can call action of controller using ajax request and returning json resullt containing url of file created on server  and then on success of ajax call you can download this file using some javscript code and then changing desired element's disabled property.

Check this for [more](http://jsfiddle.net/jLz39jc6/)

Comment: I have tried it and it doesnt work. Since I'm doing a window.location.href it doesnt reload the same page.

Comment: This is true but I don´t want to create files on the server if it's not necessary. For now I'm trying to find another solution.

Comment: cant u send another ajax request to delete this file immediately? there wont be an issue coz u already have file url, If possible.